MPPI cannot follow path accurately
I'm currently using mppi controller nav2 in a differential robot. It work pretty well in the simulation, but when I try it in my physics robot, it look like that the robot cannot follow the path accurately, since the angular velocity of mppi output is too small to turn sharply. And I also find out that the optimal trajectory is not in the generated trajectories region showing in the following video.


My controller params are:
controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]
    # Goal checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController"
      time_steps: 56
      model_dt: 0.05
      batch_size: 2000
      vx_std: 0.2
      vy_std: 0.2
      wz_std: 0.25 # 0.4
      vx_max: 0.5 # 1.5 # 0.5
      vx_min: -0.35 # -1.05 # -0.35
      vy_max: 0.5
      wz_max: 1.9
      iteration_count: 1
      prune_distance: 4.2 # 3.7 # 1.7 (must )
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      temperature: 0.3
      gamma: 0.015
      motion_model: "DiffDrive" #Ackermann, DiffDrive
      visualize: false
      reset_period: 1.0 # (only in Humble)
      regenerate_noises: false
      TrajectoryVisualizer:
        trajectory_step: 5
        time_step: 3
      AckermannConstraints:
        min_turning_r: 0.5
      critics: ["ConstraintCritic", "CostCritic", "ObstaclesCritic", "GoalCritic", "GoalAngleCritic", "PathAlignCritic", "PathFollowCritic", "PathAngleCritic", "PreferForwardCritic"]
      # critics: ["ConstraintCritic", "CostCritic", "GoalCritic", "GoalAngleCritic", "PathAlignCritic", "PathFollowCritic", "PathAngleCritic", "PreferForwardCritic"]
      ConstraintCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 4.0
      GoalCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4
      GoalAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 3.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
      PreferForwardCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
      ObstaclesCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        repulsion_weight: 1.0 # 1.5
        critical_weight: 20.0
        consider_footprint: true
        collision_cost: 100000.0
        collision_margin_distance: 0.1
        near_goal_distance: 0.1 # 0.5 # Smaller value to avoid near goal collision
        inflation_radius: 1.0 # 0.75 # 0.55 # 0.6 # (only in Humble)
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 # (only in Humble)
      CostCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 3.81
        critical_cost: 300.0
        consider_footprint: true
        collision_cost: 1000000.0
        near_goal_distance: 0.1 # 1.0 # Smaller value to avoid near goal collision
        trajectory_point_step: 2
      PathAlignCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 14.0
        max_path_occupancy_ratio: 0.05
        trajectory_point_step: 3
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        offset_from_furthest: 20
        use_path_orientations: false
      PathFollowCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        offset_from_furthest: 5
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4
      PathAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 2.0
        offset_from_furthest: 4
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        max_angle_to_furthest: 1.0
        mode: 2
      TwirlingCritic:
        enabled: true
        twirling_cost_power: 1
        twirling_cost_weight: 10.0


what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

I want the mppi controller can follow the global path accurately, but just as the GIFs show, it didn't work like that. Please tell me what else details should I apply to help you to understand this question?

What is your compute platform? What branch? How did you install it? What ROS distribution? Did you try the default parameters? This is lacking useful information needed to help :(

the compute platform is NVIDIA orin nx, the ROS distribution is humble and we install navigation2 via source code. We have tried the default parameters, however it did not work well. Besides, the parameters we are using performs well in simulation. Is there any one having ideas about the gap between simulation and real-world?

Hi! I experienced the same problem when running on an nvidia platform as well. Expended some time debugging and traced the problem back to the integrateStateVelocities function in optimizer.cpp. Rolling those functions the commit before this pr  seemed to have solved the problem for me. This seems to happen only on ARM.
